# Android Official Icons for XXHDPI and XXXHDPI

Tags: android, icons, screen-resolution

With screen resolutions increasing in pixels Google is promoting the use of XXHDPI and XXXHDPI, icons in the official documents.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

But in their official Android download packs they only go up to XHDPI.

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Do they expect us to create these icons when can't be bothered too?

What are other developers doing especially for the Holo icons, are they creating it from SVG.

**Update**

If you download the the Icon Pack and not the "all pack", it now contains XXHDPI icons but still no XXXHDPI.

http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip

Comment: Id go with using XHDPI for now and wait for the official packs to be updated.

Comment: @Poldie XXHDPI describes DPI not inches, you may have 50+inch tv having mdpi or xhdpi.....

Comment: Google is making fun from us. However, I found some XXHDPI icons in GIT repository of some app.

Answer (score 3):

Since they provide ai file, which is vector-based, you can export any scale you want.

Btw, Nexus 5 (and many other 1080p phones) is already XXHDPI, so you are supposed to provide at least XXHDPI icons.

Comment: Nexus 5 launcher icons must be xxxhdpi.

Answer (score 3):

As the updated question already says: The official Android icon pack now contains the XXXHDPI icons.

Comment: This is not true. For example Nexus 6 uses xxxhdpi resources. http://goo.gl/zoR4ji

Other devices with QHD displays probably are using them as well, the Galaxy S6 for sure.

Comment: When I posted this, it was true :-) - and there was no S6 or Nexus 6

Comment: I wrote it just to inform others, not to let you down. Just the way stackoverflow works. Probably I have outdated answers around here.

Comment: Try reading that update again, it says **yes** `xxdpi`, **no** `xxxhdpi`.

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 6 is somewhere between xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.  Google has recently started to encourage the usage of xxxhdpi icons, as you can see here...https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Comment: Could you please check exactly is Nexus xxxhdpi device using https://github.com/mportuesisf/ScreenInfo 
see also https://github.com/paulvi/displayclasses

Comment: I know what I write. It's not necessary to check it. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html?m=1

Comment: This is the right answer, it should be replaced on http://developer.android.com. I opened a request for that: http://b.android.com/161513, star it if you care.