# Android: Are there xxxhdpi density devices?

Tags: android

Are there xxxhdpi density devices?

Android devices screen density increases (see https://github.com/paulvi/displayclasses) and there are already devices with density higher than xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi

like Samsung Galaxy S6      577     2560    1440

(But I cannot check if it is really xxxhdpi)

**Is it time to prepare 192x192 icons?**
(4x times 48x48 dp, see http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html )

See also [Android Official Icons for XXHDPI and XXXHDPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858398/android-official-icons-for-xxhdpi-and-xxxhdpi)

UPDATE: Was asked a year before as [Android xxx-hdpi real devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452353/android-xxx-hdpi-real-devices)

Also [Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 Screen density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602229/nexus-6-and-nexus-9-screen-density)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just for reference purpose, now Google maintain a list of devices density and other information at https://design.google.com/devices/ which is mainly targeted for material design guideline.

Comment: Sadly, it isn't updated. But I guess it gives you some guide to calculate yourself.

Comment: Note that this lists the Galaxy S7 for example as `4.0 xxxhdpi` which is misleading. You can use the S7 in that mode but by default it scales down to a lower resolution which is `3.0 xxhdpi`, and most users don't change defaults.

Comment: Link is broken as of 2023-05-17

Answer (score 6):

> Are there xxxhdpi density devices?

Afaik Nexus 6 is `xxxhdpi` device

Comment: Not really, though it will use xxxhdpi if `drawable-560dpi` does not have the resource. Its actually physically closest to xxhdpi, but the mid-density of 560 dpi was chosen by manufacturer.  For example, [Why Nexus 6 density is 560 dpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477572/why-nexus-6-density-is-560-dpi)

Answer (score 2):

New phones already use XXXHDPI.
Our test phone Samsung S6 Edge use xxxhdpi drawable resources. Someone already mentioned that Nexus 6 also using this dimension. Thus new phones with good screen should use this dimension.

Answer (score 1):

My Samsung S22, released in February 25, 2022, has a 600 dpi when resolution is set to its highest (3088 x 1440), and more importantly, it loads xxhdpi resources, which means that we aren't there yet in terms of smartphones with 640 DPI or more screen density, and even if your phone contains 600 dpi like my S22 does, which is just 40 dpi shy off 640, it'll still load the 480 dpi (xxhdpi) resources.

I guess we'll get to 640 dpi in a year or two, I also expect the AOSP to add a xxxxhdpi to the source code very soon just as xxxhdpi was added in 2013, long before any 640 dpi handset was released.

Answer (score 0):

xxxhdpi density devices Resolutions :

```
2048x1536
2560x1536 
2560x1600


In Nexus 6
```

For more help :
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: No. Pixel dimensions are **not** density. There could be a 3" phone with xxxhdpi density. OTOH, there could be a 10" tablet with hdpi density. These might have similar # pixels. The *pixel resolution* does not indicate the density; must take into account device size, if calculating. But ultimately, you have to ask the device what density it claims to be.

Comment: "The pixel resolution does not indicate the density" Well considering a typical sized phone it would give you a good idea when comparing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, even as of 2016, there are still no xxxhdpi device.

The largest resolution on Android device is used by Xperia Z5 Premium (4k on 5.5", or roughly 806ppi), and even on that device, it was only used that humongous screen density for multimedia contents. The UI itself was rendered by halving the effective density by two, so it actually scales down from 4k to full HD on 5.5", or xxhdpi.

Specs for Xperia Z5 Premium : http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_z5_premium-7536.php

Comment: It is now 2017 and all the premium flagships seem to be xxxhdpi: https://material.io/devices/

Answer (score 0):

I found 8 corresponding devices [here](https://material.io/tools/devices/).

Comment: On this page it says that Samsung S7 is xxxhdpi, but I have this device and it loads xxhdpi resources.

Comment: You can switch it to "High performance" mode, and it will switch to xxxhdpi, but with default settings it is set to xxhdpi